# Using i18n .properties-defined maps in a UiBinder template

Tags: gwt

Suppose I have a `<String,String>` map defined in my i18n .properties files, e.g.:

```
userGroupMap = 0, 1, 2, 3
0=Factory 
1=Administrators
2=Superusers
3=Operators
```

The dev guide [explains](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nConstants#ConstantsProperties) that introducing a corresponding `Map<String,String> userGroupMap()` method in `MyConstants implements Constants` interface will result in calls such as `MyConstants.userGroupMap().get("1")` returning the localized `"Administrators"`. So far so good.

What about UiBinder? How do I use one of the mapped values in a UiBinder template? Is there a syntax I'm missing, e.g. `<ui:msg key="userGroupMap:1">Administrators</ui:msg>` (doesn't actually work)?

Comment: Realized (and tested) that `userGroupMap = 0, 1, 2, 3` is a sort of an aggregator of existing keys, so `<ui:msg key="1">` works. The question still stands, however: is there a way to incorporate `userGroupMap` as context for the `0,1,2,3` keyset in UiBinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this would be a non-xml solution, but you could use a @UiFactory to help with the creation of the specific fields or labels that you need I18N'd.  But to me, this particular problems seems like it begs the solution below, since you seem to be looking to decouple your widgets from your screen or panel layouts.

I struggled with this, and for my implementation, I ended up making core widgets with UiBinder backing for their internals(for instance a label and a text field with a help button), and then passing in a 'fieldKey' that was used as a prepender for all the I18N keys in the various maps.

For instance, for the PartNumber field, I had a key in the following maps: labelTexts(), helpTexts(), tooltipTexts(), defaultFieldValues().  Then in the constructor for that widget, I would pass in the string key 'partNumber', and that would be used to build up all the keys needed, so I would call labelTexts().get('partNumberLabelText'), helpTexts().get('partNumberHelpText'), etc.

I didn't want to do this directly in UiBinder, since I wanted the widget key to map back to it's display information, so I could create a widget with as little input information as possible, in many cases just the key and then the widget (provided it was configured in the I18N setup correctly) would just populate everything from the maps based on that.

From a design standpoint, for me it didn't make sense to have separate UiBinders for the screen sets, they were composited from objects that defined the screen layout and relation of all the widgets (meaning that you could define screen content at runtime).

Comment: I ended up with the same solution of prefixing keys to give them context, e.g. `group_0`, `group_1`, etc. where subsequently I would query the map using `myGroupMap.get("group_" + String.valueOf(grpId))`.